# What does するって mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, particle-って

I am trying to understand the role of するって and its meaning.

> ２４じかんこうどう　ともに　するって　こういうこと

Comment: ((２４じかんこうどう　ともに　する) って)　こういうこと. Does it make sense now that I split things up like this?

Comment: I think now i understand. It becomes "I share these things from 24 hours" i guess, right?

Comment: "on a mission" is pretty bad as a translation of 行動. I take the text to be this: 24時間行動　共に　するって　こういうこと. When you said "doing an activity together for 24 hours, this is what you mean"

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't see how you get mission from 行動...

Answer (score 5):

って ＝ というのは in meaning.

「って」 is an **informal topic-introducing marker** that is frequently used in casual conversations.

「24[時間]{じかん}[行動]{こうどう}（を）[共]{とも}にするって、こういうこと（だ）。」

「Aって、こういうこと（だ）。」 = ***"This is what A means."***

A = Spending 24 hours with someone / Being with someone at all times